# Enumerate shared folders on Windows with low privileges

Tags: c++, windows, shared-directory

Using C++ (VS2008) I need to be able to enumerate all shared folders on the current machine and get or construct the local and remote names.

We've been using [`NetShareEnum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb525387(VS.85).aspx) for this fairly successfully, but have hit a problem where we need to run with a user account with low privileges.

To get the local path using `NetShareEnum` we need to retrieve at least [`SHARE_INFO_2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb525410(v=VS.85).aspx) structures - but that requires "*Administrator, Power User, Print Operator, or Server Operator group membership*".

I've been trying to use [`WNetOpenEnum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385478(v=VS.85).aspx) and [`WNetEnumResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385449(VS.85).aspx) instead but I don't seem to be getting the local name back for that for shares either. AFAICS it only enumerates the shares from an external perspective.

So I'd either like help on where I'm going wrong with `WNetEnumResource`, or a suggestion as to another way of doing this. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an idea what the local path would be, you can brute-force it by testing: (TODO: make everything Unicode)

```
// Helper function to make a name unique.
std::string computername()
{
    static std::string name = []() {
        WCHAR buf[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH];
        DWORD len = MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH;
        GetComputerNameEx(ComputerNameNetBIOS, buf, &len);
        return std::string(buf, buf + len);
    }();
    return name;
}

int main()
{
    std::string dir = "C:\\FindThisShare\\";
    // First, create marker
    std::string testfile = computername() + " 038D2B86-7459-417B-9179-90CEECC6EC9D.txt";
    std::ofstream test(dir + testfile);
    test << "This directory holds files from " << computername() 
         << std::endl;
    test.close();

    // Next, find the UNC path holding it.
    BYTE* buf;
    DWORD numEntries;
    NetShareEnum(nullptr, 1, &buf, MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH, &numEntries,
                 &numEntries, nullptr);
    auto data = reinterpret_cast<SHARE_INFO_1*>(buf);
    std::string retval;
    for (int i = 0; i != numEntries; ++i)
    {
        auto const& entry = data[i];
        std::wstring tmp(entry.shi1_netname);
        std::string share(tmp.begin(), tmp.end());
        std::string uncdir = "\\\\" + computername() + "\\" + share + "\\";
        if (PathFileExistsA((uncdir + testfile).c_str()))
        {
            printf("Exists");
        }
    }
    remove((dir + testfile).c_str());
    NetApiBufferFree(buf);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're specifying `RESOURCE_GLOBALNET` for the scope, but it's hard to tell what's wrong without seeing your code.

It's hard to help without knowing what you tried and what you got back. For example, what local name are you expecting and what is getting returned? Did you try NetShareEnum with SHARE_INFO_503?

Comment: I tried all combinations of flags for the first parameter to WNetOpenEnum, but only RESOURCE_GLOBALNET seemed to let me enumerate shares at all. If you know different I'd be happy to give it a try. I've just been using the sample code from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385341(VS.85).aspx and have hacked it about in a few different ways - none of which have been very productive, so I didn't post the code.

Comment: The sample code you linked to is recursive so it enumerates the whole network. Are you saying that you don't know how to make it not recursive? Just pass in the NETRESOURCE corresponding to the local machine.

Comment: From what I could see there wasn't a way to get at the NETRESOURCE for the local machine without potentially iterating the whole network to get it - is there a shortcut?

Comment: TBH I didn't spend too much time looking at that as I was more concerned with the fact that the local name was coming back as NULL anyway. Any ideas on that? I can look at the "whole network" part again.

Comment: Ok, I've edited my question to focus on the "local name" part. I'm still not sure how to get to the local machine without having to enumerate through other machines first (although I don't have to enumerate the shares on those machines, of course.

Comment: Sorry, I only just noticed your update about SHARE_INFO_503. That still requires the higher privilege level - and is not available for XP and W2003, which is our requirement.